# Function redeclaration on C++

Tags: c++

I have been reviewing the implementation of a tool and I observed something unusual.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED __attribute__ ((unused))
#else
#define VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED
#endif
    static VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED void load_vertex_intervals(std::string base_filename, int nshards, std::vector<std::pair<vid_t, vid_t> > & intervals, bool allowfail);
    static VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED void load_vertex_intervals(std::string base_filename, int nshards, std::vector<std::pair<vid_t, vid_t> > & intervals, bool allowfail=false) {
        std::string intervalsFilename = filename_intervals(base_filename, nshards);
        std::ifstream intervalsF(intervalsFilename.c_str());

        if (!intervalsF.good()) {
            if (allowfail) return; // Hack
            logstream(LOG_ERROR) << "Could not load intervals-file: " << intervalsFilename << std::endl;
        }
        assert(intervalsF.good());

        intervals.clear();

        vid_t st=0, en;
        for(int i=0; i < nshards; i++) {
            assert(!intervalsF.eof());
            intervalsF >> en;
            intervals.push_back(std::pair<vid_t,vid_t>(st, en));
            st = en + 1;
        }
        for(int i=0; i < nshards; i++) {
            logstream(LOG_INFO) << "shard: " << intervals[i].first << " - " << intervals[i].second << std::endl;
        }
        intervalsF.close();
    }
```

Why is the declaration of the function above the implementation? What is the use of this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Posted the code, instead of the simplified example

Comment: It's useless, someone forgot to remove it.

Comment: I'd suspect this isn't the real code you post here. Is `fun()` calling itself recursively?

Comment: Here it is useless, as @101010 said.

Answer (score 2):

The simplies example of this is when you need to use this function from a lot of places:

```
static void fun(int x);

static void f() {
    fun(5);
}

static void fun(int x) {
    cout<<"X = "<<x<<endl;
}
```

Without declaration it will not compile because in f()::fun(5) call compiler does not know that this function is exists. The declaration says (afaik it is called "prototype") that this function is exists and defined somewhere (will be checked after).

Without this prototype you will get compiler error:

```
t.cpp: In function ‘void f()’:
t.cpp:20:10: error: ‘fun’ was not declared in this scope
```

UPD: in code you posted here this declaration makes no sense at all.
In

```
static VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED void load_vertex_intervals(std::string base_filename, int nshards, std::vector<std::pair<vid_t, vid_t> > & intervals, bool allowfail);
static VARIABLE_IS_NOT_USED void load_vertex_intervals(std::string base_filename, int nshards, std::vector<std::pair<vid_t, vid_t> > & intervals, bool allowfail=false) {
```

you may delete first line with the declaration.

Comment: What you describe makes sense, but this isn't what the OP is reporting. He tells us that they are imediatly next one to another. (but is it really that way ?)

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it doesn't have much point. However, in general, even if this is all inside a cpp file, it does give you the flexibility to move definitions around.

E.g.

```
 void foo()
 {}

 void bar() 
 {
      foo();
 }
```

is OK, but if you later decide that it's the other way around, and actually `foo` needed to call `bar`, then the order is a problem.

If you start off with

```
void foo();
void bar();

... 

// definitions
```

Then you can move the definitions around (just not over the declarations) as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need the declaration. The declaration becomes useful if you add a new function that calls fun preceding fun's definition. The function declaration would give the new function enough details about how to call fun to allow it to compile.